# postfix relay - send message to a non-existing mail address does not fail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, relay

I have a docker-mailserver with a relay on a tiers server (Oracle cloud email delivery).

When I send a message to a non-existing address (e.g. to gmail), I get a Code 250 Ok Sent (should not it be a code 550 ?), but I would like to receive an email in the sender mailbox saying something like "The message could not be sent to {someaddresswichdoesnotexist}."

Here are some logs:

```
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<contact@my-domain.org>, method=PLAIN, rip=my-ip, lip=172.19.0.5, mpid=6461, TLS, session=<wJCqNOLiYt6M7tku>
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6462]: connect from unknown[my-ip]
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6462]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[my-ip]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (4096 bits) server-digest SHA256
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6462]: AFDDEFD48F: client=unknown[my-ip], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=contact@my-domain.org
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[6467]: AFDDEFD48F: replace: header MIME-Version: 1.0 from unknown[my-ip]; from=<contact@my-domain.org> to=<EFC370246DA40A0B17C288103EF@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.my-domain.org>: Mime-Version: 1.0
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[6467]: AFDDEFD48F: message-id=<e860ccc620b36af95cd3b7cf5bed326e@my-domain.org>
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail opendkim[260]: AFDDEFD48F: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=my-domain.org)
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/qmgr[1471]: AFDDEFD48F: from=<contact@my-domain.org>, size=936, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[6462]: disconnect from unknown[my-ip] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail dovecot: imap(contact@my-domain.org)<6461><wJCqNOLiYt6M7tku>: Logged out in=972 out=573 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<contact@my-domain.org>, method=PLAIN, rip=my-ip, lip=172.19.0.5, mpid=6474, TLS, session=<O8GvNOLiZN6M7tku>
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail dovecot: imap(contact@my-domain.org)<6474><O8GvNOLiZN6M7tku>: Logged out in=90 out=1054 deleted=0 expunged=0 trashed=0 hdr_count=0 hdr_bytes=0 body_count=0 body_bytes=0
Jul  3 08:14:17 mail postfix/smtp[6468]: Trusted TLS connection established to smtp.email.eu-zurich-1.oci.oraclecloud.com[192.29.182.152]:587: TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 (256/256 bits)
Jul  3 08:14:18 mail postfix/smtp[6468]: AFDDEFD48F: to=<EFC370246DA40A0B17C288103EF@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.email.eu-zurich-1.oci.oraclecloud.com[192.29.182.152]:587, delay=0.46, delays=0.08/0.02/0.22/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok)
Jul  3 08:14:18 mail postfix/qmgr[1471]: AFDDEFD48F: removed
```

How can I configure a delivery failure message on my local setup (I have a rainloop client) ?

Comment: Your mail server successfully hands over the smtp message to the relay, which is why you get a success exit code. Only once the relay has received the message and closed the connection to your mail server, the relay will initiate delivery to the next hop. When that doesn't succeed it is up to the relay server to send a bounce/email delivery failure notification. You don't control that from your end.

Comment: Usually the reason for not being able to post is not formatting the logs as inline code or within code blocks, because the logs have (or even if they appear to have) a lot of links in them.